# How can I upgrade the plane at McKenzie Airfield?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is is possible to purchase/steal a better plane for use on the McKenzie Airfield missions?

If so, how do I do it?

Comment: You can always steal a better plane from the Military Airbase but I am almost positive you cannot use it for the package drop missions.    I can test this tonight if no one answers by then  or I don't find an answer.

Comment: No, I'm fairly certain you can't use another plane for those missions. It's pretty much like you can't perform taxi missions in a sports car (unless you own the cab business and they call you for help, but those are escort missions rather than taxi ones)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid that the plane you use for the package drop/bombing missions from the Mexican guy as Trevor is what gives you the mission. You can not use a different plane for this, in the same way that you can't use anything other than the off-road buggy for the ground-based arms race missions.

Comment: What about starting the mission with the given plane, then switching during the mission?

Comment: Exiting the plane fails the mission, IIRC.

Comment: Wishful thinking, I guess. That plane sucks.

Comment: @ChargingPun i think that plane is still better than the one we use to tail the Merryweather cargo plane earlier in the game.

Comment: @Dredd Funny, I actually prefer that one. It's more maneuverable.

Comment: haha. i hate that duster plane or whatever its called & sometimes i feel in the drug trafficking missions when i perform the drop outside the drop zone it becomes a successful drop but when i try to do it near the flares it becomes a miss.

Answer (score 1):

No sorry you have to put up with that plane.
The best you can do is save a different airplane there but you can't use that for missions